# How to get date type value from object?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to get all the values from an object whose data type is a date.
How does that possible. And also after that, I want to convert it into UTC and save it.

```
e.g.
{
    employeeid: "4",
    id: 276,
    birthdate: "Thu Mar 26 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
    status: "pending"
}
```

From this object I just want birthdate(I won't be knowing the property name it can be anything). I want to make this code generic because the variable name varies and I want to use this for the whole application.

Comment: The general answer would be to filter the values by `instanceof Date`, but some more context would be helpful. Give a [mre] of your current efforts.

Comment: The object you're showing has `birthdate` as a _string_. Is that just the JSON output of the object and the property is actually a `Date`, or are you looking to detect _strings_ that resemble a date?

Comment: @Jacob yes right

Comment: @jonrsharpe What do u want to know more about can you please explain

Comment: What output do you expect from this? What about strings that don't match that exact format but can be parsed to dates? *What have you tried*?

Comment: forget about the conversion. I just expect the value whose type is date. Now the payload can be json or array of objects. So the challenge for me is how to get the key and value of type date from the payload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse a string as a date. If the string is a valid date then it returns a number representing the milliseconds elapsed since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC, otherwise, it returns `NaN`.

```js
/**
 * Check if the string is a valid date string or not.
 * For that we check if the given string is really a string, not a number.
 * Because a number is parsed as a date by Date.parse()
 */
function isDate(str) {
    let date = Date.parse(str);
    return (typeof str === 'object' && str instanceof Date) || (typeof str === 'string' && isNaN(+str) && !isNaN(date));
}

/**
 * These are some examples
 *
 */
let dateString = "Thu Mar 26 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)";
let nonDateString = "Hello world";
let object = {
    employeeid: "4",
    id: 276,
    birthdate: "Thu Mar 26 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
    status: "pending"
};


console.log('Date string: ', isDate(dateString));
console.log('Non date string:', isDate(nonDateString));

// Check a date object rather than a date string. It works for it as well.
console.log('Date object:', isDate(new Date()));

if (isDate(object.birthdate)) {
    console.log(`${object.birthdate}: is a date string.`);
} else {
    console.log(`${object.birthdate}: is not a date string.`);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0;}
```

### Update

For your changed query I am updating this answer. As you need all the values of the object with date strings so for that I am generating a new object with all the dates and converts the date strings to UTC string.

```js
/**
* Check if a string is a date or not.
*/
function isDate(str) {
    let date = Date.parse(str);
    return (typeof str === 'object' && str instanceof Date) || (typeof str === 'string' && isNaN(+str) && !isNaN(date));
}


const obj = {
    employeeid: "4",
    id: 276,
    birthdate: "Thu Mar 26 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
    status: "pending",
 join: Date('2020-01-12')
};

/**
* This will makes a new object with the date types
* and also convert the date into a UTC string.
*/
const dates = Object.entries(obj).reduce((a, [key, value]) => {
    return isDate(value) ? {...a, [key]: new Date(value).toUTCString()} : a;
}, {});

console.log(dates);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100%!important; top: 0;}
```

Comment: exactly.  He shouldn't have to convert the result to utc because it should already contain utc in it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I want to make this generic. I wont be knowing the exact property name which will be of date type. That's what I need. I want to get the value which is of date type into the payload. I heard about prototype. But unable to crack it.

Comment: Please check my updated answer. If you need the output structure other than the given one then feel free to know me. As I really don't understand what would be the exact output of you are wanting.

Comment: I could not understand " typeof str === 'string' && isNaN(+str) && !isNaN(date); "
Can you please explain this.
And also sometimes my date field was coming as an obj so i made some changes as:
"  return typeof str == 'string' && isNaN(+str) && !isNaN(date) || Object.prototype.toString.call(str) === '[object Date]'; "

I checked if the object type is date. And now this is giving me perfect output. Giving me dates from the payload

Comment: Sorry, I think it always is a date string. Can you give me an example of a date object?

Comment: Inside an object, I think it always is a string.

Comment: date: Sun Apr 05 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
__proto__: Object

I am getting my date like this... and can you please explain what exactly " ypeof str === 'string' && isNaN(+str) && !isNaN(date); " this do

Comment: Actually previously I was thinking that the field must be a date string. So, if it's a date object then you have to check if it's an ```instanceof Date```.  And the line ```typeof str === 'string' && isNaN(+str) && !isNaN(date)``` means, first I check it's a string or not. If it's not a string, say a number then return false. ```isNaN(+str)``` means if a number inside a quote like ```"4"``` the ```Date.parse()``` treat this like a number and makes miliseconds. So first convert it as a number by using +str then check if it's returns NaN or not.

Comment: Note: I've updated my answer for date object check.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `instanceof` and `typeof` to check data type.

I made an demo to check your data type

```
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular";
  mydata = {
    employeeid: "4",
    id: 276,
    birthdate: "Thu Mar 26 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
    status: "pending"
  };
  birthdayType: any;
  realType: any;

  constructor() {
    let dob: any = this.mydata.birthdate;
    this.birthdayType = dob instanceof Date;
    this.realType = typeof dob;
  }
}

export class Data {
  public employeeid: string;
  public id: number;
  public birthday: Date;
  public status: string;
}
```

Stackbliz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bw4b8d

Comment: Yes you are right, but actually I have to make this generic. I have to check if the object has a value of type date when i was about to post the payload to the api. So I dont know if there will be birthdate or any other property name